# Delay between speech and voice recognition

Tags: android

I'd like to add a delay between the text to speech and the subsequent voice recognition but don't know enough about wait/sleep statements and the concept of not blocking the main thread.  Could I have suggestions on how to achieve a wait until the text to speech is finished speaking and the voice recognition starting.

```
                String myText1 = "Please speak the new speedlimit";
                mTts.speak(myText1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                speechSucess = true;
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` and call `startVoiceRecognitionActivity();` from the listener's callback function:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)