# adding a delay to tts

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a part of my program that uses the TTS engine in a service but I want to add a 3 second delay from when it should be done so that it does not overlap with other audio that would be playing. how can I put that 3 second delay in?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308542/delay-between-speech-and-voice-recognition

Comment: no he is trying to accomplish something totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the thread concept. Make a new thread and place the part of code which uses TTS engine in a service and give delay.

Comment: what do you mean give it a delay? do you mean use `thread.sleep(delayTime)`?

Comment: Yes, you can try this. I am not sure but I think it will work.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I've got nothing against your solution. But... what a very bad thing. This is one of the aspects of the Android SDK that make me hate it.